# Adding regression line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a regression line to my scatterplot using the following snippet of code

```
library(ggplot2)
CouncilNames <- c("Antrim and Newtownabbey", "Armagh City, Banbridge and Craigavon", "Causeway Coast and Glens", "Lisburn and Castlereagh", "Mid and East Antrim", "Mid Ulster", "Newry, Mourne and Down")
NumberOfFoodPlaces <- c(110, 170,124, 94, 114, 140, 129)
NumberOfStrayDogs <- c(525, 878, 454, 409, 762, 455, 894)

df <- data.frame(CouncilNames, NumberOfStrayDogs, NumberOfFoodPlaces)
df


plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=NumberOfFoodPlaces, y=NumberOfStrayDogs, group = CouncilNames, 
                       colour = CouncilNames)) + 
  geom_point() + labs(y="No. of Stray Dogs", x = "No.of Food Establishments") + 
  ggtitle("Correlation between the No. of Stray Dogs and the No.of Food Establishments")
plot

plot + geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm")

cor(df$NumberOfFoodPlaces, df$NumberOfStrayDogs)
test <- cor.test(df$NumberOfFoodPlaces, df$NumberOfStrayDogs)
test
```

However, the regression line isn't appearing and the only issue I can see is `` > plot `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x' `` is highlighted red in the console. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stack ! Please, try to give a minimal reproducible example by giving a toy dataset or using `dput` on your data, see [mcve]

Comment: Hi @denis! Please see above the amended code of the exact plot I am creating

Answer (score 5):

The `geom_smooth` function operates by color and group. Since each color has only a single point, a line cannot be created. Instead, you must move these aesthetics to `geom_point` so that all of the data is considered by `geom_smooth`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=NumberOfFoodPlaces, y=NumberOfStrayDogs)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = CouncilNames, group = CouncilNames)) +
  labs(y="No. of Stray Dogs", x = "No.of Food Establishments") + 
  ggtitle("Correlation between the No. of Stray Dogs and the No.of Food Establishments") +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Ah that make's total sense now!! Thank you so much